# Vuejs: inject & load vue component only when another component is emiting an event

Tags: symfony, vue.js

I'm working with Symfony >4.2 and the latest vestion of vuejs.
So i have a component exposing different filters (price, size .. blablabla) and another component displaying product results. What i would like to do is **first display all products** by default (no filters selected) **with symfony/twig** (so that i can actually see the html in the source code of my navigator) **in the #display-component div**.

Then secondly, **as soon as a user changes a filter, the vue display component should be injected in #display-component**, and take over from that moment (it can update, delete, add, whatever..). But i really need that first render with twig.

Example:

```
<div id="#display-component">
   <div class="product"> </div>
   <div class="product"> </div>
   <div class="product"> </div>
</div>
```

```js
new Vue({
    el: '#display-component',
    components: {
        'DisplayComponent': DisplayComponent
    },
    template: '<DisplayComponent/>'
});
```

I really don't know if its possible. It seems that if i hook the display component, i always loose the content of the div where it is being injected. I'm not showing code because it is quiet long. I would really appreciate a very simple POC, if someone has a solution !

Comment: seems like using custom directives might work?

Comment: Maybe you should take a look at [Dynamic & Async Components](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html#ad).

Comment: Thanks fort the hints, im still new to vue, ill look into it